# JQuery: on('click') fires without click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to update the value of the `"right"` property before clicking on the `next1` or `prev1` button. So I have used the `.on(mouseover)` event and also the `on.(click)` event.

It's almost working, but sometimes without clicking any button, the click event is fired and nothing works properly.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // for next button
  $('a.next1').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('div.slide_2').css("right", "-55%");
    $('div.slide_3').css("right", "-55%");
  });
  $('a.next2').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('div.slide_3').css("right", "-55%");
    $('div.slide_1').css("right", "-55%");
  });
  $('a.next3').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('div.slide_1').css("right", "-55%");
    $('div.slide_2').css("right", "-55%");
  });

  $('a.next1').on('click', function() {
    $('div.slide_1').css({
      "right": "105%",
      "opacity": "0"
    });
    $('div.slide_2').css({
      "right": "25%",
      "opacity": "1"
    });
  });

  $('a.next2').on('click', function() {
    $('div.slide_2').css({
      "right": "105%",
      "opacity": "0"
    });
    $('div.slide_3').css({
      "right": "25%",
      "opacity": "1"
    });
  });

  $('a.next3').on('click', function() {
    $('div.slide_3').css({
      "right": "105%",
      "opacity": "0"
    });
    $('div.slide_1').css({
      "right": "25%",
      "opacity": "1"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide_1" data-number="1">
  <img src="image1.jpg">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  <a class="prev1" data-number="2">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next1" data-number="0">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="slide_2 mySlides" data-number="2">
  <img src="image2.jpg">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  <a class="prev2" data-number="2">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next2" data-number="0">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<div class="slide_3 mySlides" data-number="3">
  <img src="image3.jpg">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  <a class="prev3" data-number="2">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next3" data-number="0">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

There is same code for the prev buttons.

Comment: Are you sure the click event is the one that's getting fired? Do a console output in each of these function handlers to see which one is getting triggered.

Comment: No, I didn't see the console output, but the visual output on the browser. @ Aakash Verma